# Getting Error in style.xml file in android studio.Can not resolve symbol theme.Validates resource references inside Android XML files

Tags: android-studio

The Application build and run correctly and there is no error in gradle build but the style.xml shows error.

I am using android studio 3.1 gradle version 4.4

[Please see The Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv6B5.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. from the top menu File -> Close project.
2. Remove it from the projects list.
3. Open existing project -> choose the project folder.